# Create Byte Array Refactoring

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I need to create byte array for testing. I implemented my own solution but not sure if it is optimal. Here it is:

```
byte counter = 0;
Func<int, byte[]> createByteArray = size =>
{
    var array = new byte[size];
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        array[index] = counter++;

        if (counter == byte.MaxValue)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return array;
};
```

Are there any ways to simplify this?

Comment: Why are you declaring `counter` outside of the function?  Are you aware of potential issues with variable closure?

Comment: so you wish to create an array of size x and fill it with numbers which increment? does the array need to contain incremental numbers?

Comment: @Mark yes, I'd like to have an array with incremental numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure this is better or not, but shorter.

```
Func<int, byte[]> createByteArray = size => Enumerable.Range(0, size)
                                            .Select(i => (byte)(i % 256))
                                            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's for testing, you can create a complete random buffer using `Random.NextBytes(...)`.

If not, you don't need the branch:

```
Func<int, byte[]> createByteArray = size =>
{
    var array = new byte[size];
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        array[index] = (byte)(index & 0xFF);
    }
    return array;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You got C#! Use it!

```
byte counter = 0;
Func<int, byte[]> createByteArray = size =>
{
    var array = new byte[size];
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        unchecked 
        {
            array[index] = counter++;
        }
    }
    return array;
};
```

Not sure why you got the `counter` outside. But If you like it this way...

Use the `unchecked` block to allow number overflowing in there. That will limit your value to what ever is possible in the `byte` range automatically.

I don't know how big the arrays are you are generating. If the generation speed is a issue and the arrays are very large you could only fill the values 0 to 255  by hand and after that is done start to copy the chucks into the remaining array. See [`Array.ConstrainedCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/x7c7c079(v=vs.100).aspx) for this. But this is only relevant if the array generation is too slow and the arrays are very large (n-times the range of Byte)

Comment: Actually a smart solution using unchecked, thats something you forget about sometimes.

Comment: I use VB.net so I never forget about this function. I am jealous because I don't have it. :| ;)